# Using Exoplayer to decode an MP3 and write to a file

Tags: android, decoding, exoplayer

I am new to Exoplayer and I know the primary goal of the library is to stream and play audio at a higher level than android's MediaCodec/AudioTrack.

I have noticed the github conversations about work arounds for mp3 decoding for older android API's/devices. I wanted to take advantage of this work by using exoplayer to decode mp3's and write them to disk. So I can process the PCM audio afterwards.

My basic attempt at this was to make my own MediaCodecTrackRenderer based on the MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer. My basic attempt was to put a FileOutputStream to write the buffer parameter in the method

```
 @Override
protected boolean processOutputBuffer(long positionUs, long elapsedRealtimeUs, MediaCodec codec,
                                      ByteBuffer buffer, MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo, int bufferIndex, boolean shouldSkip)
```

However the buffer that is passed in seems to still be encoded as an mp3? At least that is what the AudioTrack class thinks.

Is what I am doing possible and in the right place in the decoding playing process of Exoplayer? Any help would be greatly appreciated.